# How can I recognize if Firefox is currently playing a Youtube video using Python?

Tags: python, youtube, spotify, twitch

I had the idea to write a Python script that would pause Spotify playback when I'm starting a Youtube video and resume it when the video ends/is paused. For this I would obviously have to recognize if Firefox is currently playing a video, however I have not come up with helpful results after initial research. Does anyone know a library or similar that allows for such functionality?

Alternatively, it might just be enough to recognize audio playing from the Firefox application, since it wouldn't be bad to have the script also affect e.g. Twitch streams or similar. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

So first you probably have to check if yt is currently open on any tab:

```
def get_youtube_window_handle(driver):
    for handle in driver.window_handles:
        driver.switch_to.window(handle)

        if driver.current_url.startswith('youtube.com'):
            return handle

    return None
```

And then check if the video is paused. I guess it's way more easy to use JS and call [Youtube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) (for instance see [`player.getPlayerState()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status)).

Now in Python I am not too sure what would be the best way to do it.
Probably something like that will do a check about whether the video is paused but take it with a pinch of salt:

```
import time

def yt_video_is_paused(driver):
    start_current_time = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-current").text
    time.sleep(1)
    end_current_time = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-current").text

    return start_current_time == end_current_time
```

And you can call both functions as shown below:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
yt_tab = get_youtube_window_handle(driver)

if yt_tab: 
    driver.switch_to.window(yt_tab)
    
    if yt_video_is_paused(driver):
      # do something
```

---

You might also need to consider what should happen if Youtube is open on multiple tabs.